# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Docker override appsettings.json

Tags: docker, containers, asp.net-core-2.1, appsettings

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application with a connection string pointing to a SQL Server database. I know that is possible to override the appsettings.json from outside the container but I cannot yet figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appsettings.json in the project:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnStr": "Password=..."
  },
}
```

Docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  aspnetcore2:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionStrings__MyConnStr=Password=...
    ports:
      - "80"
```